# How to configure Nginx to forward the original error messge

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My system has two parts, front-end application and back-end appliction. I used Nginx as reverse proxy between the front-end and the back-end. 
Now, the back-end application would throw http 500 error with useful error message. And I want the front-end application could receive the error code and error message.

But, the Nginx would replace my error message with a html error page.
How to configure the Nginx to forward the original error message?

I tried to use  `proxy_next_upstream` and `up_error_code` ,but doesn't work.

```
upstream fs_web { 
    ip_hash; 
    server 172.1.0.1:8080; 
    server 172.1.0.3:8080; 
} 
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name localhost; 
    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://fs_web/; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1; 
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive; 
        proxy_set_header Keep-Alive 600; 
        keepalive_timeout 600; 
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_404; 
    }
```

Comment: Please include the minimum Nginx configuration required to reproduce this issue.

Comment: `upstream fs_web {
    ip_hash;
    server  172.1.0.1:8080;
    server  172.1.0.3:8080;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

      location / {
            proxy_pass  http://fs_web/;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Keep-Alive 600;
            keepalive_timeout 600;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_404;
    }
`

Comment: The problem maybe that you are trying to use the 500 response for two purposes: 1) selecting the next upstream, and 2) passing useful information to the client. They are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes，the content will pass the real error message. And now, it's replaced with 500.html by Nginx. And i could't disable it.